# Hide form if checkbox not checked

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I have a checkout page with a default gift option. I have this code that allows to hide the gift option altogether:

```
<script>
 $( document ).ready( function(){
 $("#gift-form").remove()
 });
</script>
```

What I'd like is for this code to not trigger if the page was accessed via the gift link. To my knowledge the gift link auto checks gift option checkbox for the user. Is this possible? Unfortunately I cannot edit the gift-form itself.

Thanks

Comment: How do get the data that the page was accessed via gift link? Is it in a query string, is it just in the URL?

Comment: When you access via the gift link it populates the checkbox automatically.

Comment: What is the selector of the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Need to know what your checkbox selector is, but you can check its value with the `checked` property:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (document.querySelector('#is_gift').checked) {
        $("#gift-form").hide();
    }
});
```

Also, if you only want to *hide* the gift option as you said, `hide()` will allow you to bring it back later (as opposed to `remove()`).

Comment: Since the rest of the page uses jQuery, it's probably better to use the `is(':checked')` jQuery listener. See my answer.

Comment: Sorry, where would I find the checkbox selector in say my source code?

Comment: I disagree. You could use `$('#checkbox')[0].checked`. Learning what is native is useful.

Comment: @N.MacPherson either send us the site, or inspect the markup for the checkbox (`Ctrl + Shift + C` or `Cmd + Alt + C` will get you into the dev tools).

Comment: I've replaced my original code with the solution but now the gift option is always vanishes (even when I access gift link)

Comment: @N.MacPherson it is not disappearing for me when I visit the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     if($('#CHECKBOX_ID').is(':checked'))
        $('#gift-form').remove()
 });
```

It sees if the checkbox is checked before removing the form.